# plotting job scheduling chart in Python

Tags: python, gantt-chart

I've a job scheduling data in a txt file in this format:

```py
 1. timestamp,jobID,start/end
 2. 0,j0,start
 3. 0,j1,start 
 4. 1,j2,start 
 5. 2,j0,end  
 6. 3,j2,end 
 7. 4,j0,start  
 8. 5,j1,end 
 9. 6,j2,start  
 10. 7,j0,end
 11. 8,j2,end
```

I want to plot this data in Python in Gantt chart style.

[image]

Please help me with basic code structure in Python as I'm new to python environment.

Comment: Welcome to SO and congrats on one of your first questions. Remember to read the guidelines on how to post questions. Avoid screenshots, format code and show the efforts you've made to solve your question.

Answer (score 2):

`matplotlib` has a function called `broken_barh()` that should get you what you want.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-basic-gantt-chart-using-matplotlib/